# Regular Expression (regex) to match LAST occurrance

Tags: regex

A regular traceroute:

```
6  ebt-b1612-tcore01.bhe.embratel.net.br (200.230.251.166)  36.006 ms  37.039 ms
   ebt-b1611-tcore01.cas.embratel.net.br (200.244.212.133)  33.340 ms
7  ebt-b10831-tcore01.spoph.embratel.net.br (200.244.212.126)  40.085 ms
   ebt-b1191-tcore01.spoph.embratel.net.br (200.230.252.14)  31.773 ms  33.899 ms
8  ebt-h0-5-0-1-puacc03.spo.embratel.net.br (200.244.214.116)  41.644 ms  33.099 ms  60.950 ms
```

What I need is to get the last .XXX. before "embratel.net.br". (in this case "spo")
I've tried a lot.. I've read a lot of stack questions and answers.. but none were helpful.

Comment: `\.[^.]*\.(?=embratel\.net\.br.*\Z)`?

Comment: I've tried something like that.. but it gives me 5 matches (https://regex101.com/r/QOjxmj/1)... And I want only the last one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/f1g22b/1/)

```
\.[^.]*\.(?=embratel\.net\.br.*\Z)
```

---

### Explanation

- `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally
- `[^.]*` Match any character except the dot character `.` any number of times
- `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally
- `(?=embratel\.net\.br.*\Z)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `embratel\.net\.br` Match this literally (`\.` matches a literal dot character `.`)
  - `.*` Match any character any number of times (this doesn't match newline characters)
  - `\Z` Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string. Alternatively, you can use `$` without the multiline `m` modifer enabled.

Comment: Correct! Just one last addition... I was trying the code to get the last word containing "eb" before the next "."(dot).. So it would get the "ebt-h0-5-0-1-puacc03" in the last line... 
I was trying something like: [^ ]*\.(?=\..*\Z) (to get the word after the space) but it, obviously didn't help it..

Comment: @TiagoAquino it really depends on the different inputs you might have. This is probably the easiest way to go about matching the *last* occurrence of `eb` though: [`.*([^.\s]*eb[^.]*).*(\.[^.\s]*\.)(?=embratel\.net\.br.*\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/f1g22b/2). Another method (isn't supported in a lot of regex engines) is [`.*\K[^.\s]*eb[^.]*(?=.*\Z)|\.[^.\s]*\.(?=embratel\.net\.br.*\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/dEKsmY/1), which doesn't contain capture groups.

Comment: Yeah.. that did it.. I gotta study regex.. You've been really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @TiagoAquino you're welcome! If you hover the tokens in regex101 it'll tell you what it does. You can also read the explanation in the top right corner, but I find it less comprehensible